# What does a 1 x 6-Pin, 1 x 6+2-Pin look like?

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply

I have this power supply http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817371016

And under the details it says

**PCI-Express Connector** 1 x 6-Pin, 1 x 6+2-Pin

However in the images of this psu it shows this [image]

I'm confused because my new graphics card requires two 6 pin pci connectors (I haven't installed my new graphics card yet.)

All i see in my psu is the 6pin pci connector with the additional 2 pins that I currently don't use on my old graphics card.  Does the nomenclature "1 x 6-Pin, 1 x 6+2-Pin" mean a total of 8 pins (1 x 6 pin, 1 x 2 pin) or does it mean a total of 14 pins?

IE the page on newegg claims to have two 6 pin pci connectors but I only see one (or maybe I read the nomenclature incorrectly)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means it has a 6 pin, and a 6+2 pin PCI connector, which makes 14 pins in total for PCI. This means you can plug it into graphics cards that needs one 6 pin, two 6 pins, one 8 pin, or one 6 pin plus one 8 pin. Here's the [proof](http://forums.penny-arcade.com/discussion/143272/computer-build-thread-embracing-web-2-0-sorta/p63)

Comment: Thanks Alex - I think I remember putting that extra cable that connects to the red end in a box somewhere... I'll go searching for it.